# count number of cells with a specific data type in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column like the following in an excel document. I need to count the number of cells with numeric value which in this case must be 5.

```
5
23
NULL
5
Eclipse
5
0
```

What I thought of is something like `countif(A1:A20, ISNUMBER)`. Please help me guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`=COUNT(A1:A20)`

From the help file:  **The COUNT function counts the number of cells that contain numbers**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c

Comment: OMG, How straightforward!! Thanks

Comment: @AfghanDeveloper - why would you want something straightforward, when you can add superfluous formulas and addition like I did? :P  I totally forgot about `Count`, and I know I have some formulas I can replace.  Thanks Darren!

Comment: Well, I was thinking of looking at each character in each cell in turn, opening calculator, parsing it to that and see if it would do a calculation - that's how I usually look at the problem. Ok, maybe not that bad but I don't always see the obvious answer either. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can use the combination of two `CountIf()` to get numbers:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4,">0")+COUNTIF(A1:A4,"<=0")
```

Or, just `=Count(A1:A4)`.